# Does nature of singularity in black hole depend on material that fell in?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry

Electromagnetic waves have a tracesless stress energy tensor, and therefore if they are the only fields in a region of spacetime, the Ricci curvature scalar $R=0$ according to GR.  However $R^{\mu\nu} \ne 0$, and other scalars of curvature can be non-zero, for example ($R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \ne 0$).

A massive scalar field provides a stress energy tensor with a non-zero trace.  Therefore $R\ne 0$.

In vacuum solutions the stress energy tensor is identically zero, so for gravity waves $R=0$ and $R^{\mu\nu}=0$.  However $R^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \ne 0$, and in particlar the curvature scalar formed from the Weyl curvature can be non-zero ($C^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}C_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$).

All of these ([even gravitational waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63749/is-it-possible-to-have-a-singularity-with-zero-mass/63791)) can collapse to a black hole.

According to the [no-hair theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) externally a blackhole will be characterized only by mass, charge, and angular momentum.  But what about internally?  Considering a collapse with no charge or total angular momentum, it seems like the above three scenarios would give qualitatively different singularities.

Comment: How would we observe the internals of a black hole? It's my understanding that the event horizon in the classical picture won't let any information (but the mass, charge and angular momentum) escape. For microscopic black holes the internals could be revealed in their decay cascade... but that's assuming that those even exist, right?

Comment: @CuriousOne I am asking about features of solutions of the Einstein field equations.  No one expects there to be actual singularities in Nature, but that would require something beyond the classical theory of GR which I am asking about here.

Comment: That's exactly my concern with being stuck in general relativity: it predicts structure on the inside, but won't let us probe from the outside. Here is a theory telling is that it will predict unlikely stuff and it won't even allow us to test that it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misinterpreting what the no-hair theorems say. There's a no-hair theorem for stationary electrovac solutions. It applies to electrovac solutions, not to solutions containing any matter field you like; in fact, there are known counterexamples if you include certain types of matter fields.

Also, it's a theorem about stationary solutions. A black hole spacetime isn't stationary inside the event horizon. It probably wouldn't make sense to talk about a uniqueness theorem extending inside the horizon, since we'd have to talk about the state of the spacetime at a certain point in time, "now," after it had, e.g., formed by gravitational collapse. But there is no usable notion of "now" that can be extended past the event horizon. One can describe all the infalling matter as only asymptotically approaching the horizon, so it has not yet passed inside the horizon "now."

A complete review article is available here: http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-1998-6/fulltext.html

Comment: I may not have explained myself well, for this seems to be misunderstanding my question. Consider some neutral matter with zero net angular momentum which is allowed to collapse and we look at the non-rotating neutral blackhole solution well after this collapse (so no angular momentum, no infalling material, and no charges) this is a GR vaccuum solution and while it is asymptotically flat at infinity it is not flat everywhere because of the other boundary condition, that with the 'matter' (singularity).

Comment: If the metric solution is stationary outside the horizon, the inside of the horizon should be static within the amount of time for the longest timelike path to the singularity.  So the blackhole should be stationary inside the horizon.  The issue you have with "now" appears to be a combination of expecting time dependence here and possily a misunderstanding of the coordinate singularity at the horizon in Schwarzschild coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Black-Hole formation is really an extension of Madame Noether's Conservation Law...where a disorganized mass of particles, in a state of 3 dimensional chaos, becomes subject to a quantum-mechanical process which 'homomorphically' transforms this chaotic state into a 2 dimensional state that has perfect Noether symmetry and equilibrium.  This transformed state consists only of radiation confined to the surface of a Schwarzschild sphere...in other words: a Black-hole. There is no internal energy, including matter, associated with the interior of a Schwarzschild sphere; and there is no singularity.

Comment: Seems some text overlap with https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/451048/25301

Comment: Hello Kyle: you are quite right about the duplication.  Sorry about the needless repetition, and I appreciate your input.