# Black hole as a gravitational spherical shell. Why not?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, black-hole-firewall

I think that Leonard Susskind's holography, George Chapline's "dark energy star," the Emil Mottola and Pawel Mazur's "Gravastar," the Polchinski's "firewall," and the recent ideas of nonsingular black holes clearly suggest possibility of understanding this phenomenon as a massive spherical shell with an asymptotically thin wall.

I think that whole mass of the black hole can be located on the same place of the surface that today we call events horizon.

What could prevent the collapse of this shell, is the hypothesis that gravity has a limit of intensity. This limit only happens in the event horizon.

I imagine that the intensity of gravity should not be infinite.
If this is possible, then black holes have no content, because inside them there would be no gravitational field, no space, no time. A place that does not really exist. A contour region of our universe.

Can a black hole be a spherical shell?

Comment: How would you  extend this idea to incorporate the conservation of angular momentum?,  as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole. Obviously, I don't know what the volume, if any, beyond the event horizon actually appears as, I am just suggesting that a spherical shell model may not fit real black holes, rather than the basic idealised model I think you have in mind, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric

Comment: @safesphere, If the idea of hollow black hole, as a gravitational spheric shell (for example) is viable, why we must still insist on the idea of singularity?

Comment: @safesphere  Yes, I understood you. As I said at the beginning, "...then black holes have no content, because within them there would be no gravitational field, no space, no time." I think the black hole is just an expanded point, inside it nothing fits, not even the Hawking radiation.

Comment: Yes, an expanded point with no content, exactly. During a neutron star collapse, the event horizon expands from the point in the center and pushes all matter out keeping it at the horizon. And no Hawking radiation obviously, because there is no singularity "inside". According to the equivalence principle, the Hawking radiation is (at least partially) equivalent to the Unruh radiation. However, there is no Unruh radiation: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0509151 - So, per the equivalence principle, there is no reason for the Hawking radiation to exist either, even if the singularity were there.

Comment: @safesphere - Why did you say it's my flaw to think a limited gravitational gradient and able to prevent the shell's collapse. I believe in this idea, I always did bet on this idea. Where is my error? Can you explain me?

Comment: Is it the new take on string theory called [straw theory](https://www.freeimageslive.co.uk/files/images007/easter_egg_on_straw.jpg), resulting in a thin and fragile shell?

Comment: @Rob - Can you develop your comment?

Comment: @safesphere, allow me to piggyback on this dialogue of yours.  We've already talked here about the limit of gravitational field strength, you disagreed.  Still on this, I note that if hypothetically black holes do not have a singularity, then the greatest intensity of their gravitational field will be located over their H.E.  However, the larger the black hole, the lower the field strength in its H.E.  This means to me that the greatest gravitational field strengths will only be found over the H.E.  of minimal black holes.  Am i wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this model of the gravitational field (a problem that was first noticed by Einstein) is that something needs to keep the mass shell from collapsing in upon itself.  The simplest way to try to do this is to suppose that the mass shell is really made up of many bodies in circular orbits around the center of mass.  This works fine, so long as the radius of the shell is larger than the Schwarzschild radius $R_{S}=\frac{2GM}{c^{2}}$ (the radius of the event horizon); however, as the radius approaches $R_{S}$, the orbital speed of particles approaches $c$, which is impossible.  (If you try to make the shell a solid, you run into a similar problem with the speed of acoustic waves that can propagate along the solid shell.)

Einstein concluded, on the basis of this kind of calculation, that black holes were not possible.  However, that is not quite correct.  What is not possible is for there to be a *static* black hole (like the mass shell model).  There is no timelike Killing vector in Schwarzschild spacetime, because at the event horizon, the variable $t$ changes from timelike to spacelike.  (And $r$ becomes timelike; this represents the fact that if you are falling into the black hole, a location at smaller $r$ must lie in in your future.)

Comment: +1 because it clarified the set up for me, but this " the orbital speed of particles approaches c, which is impossible."  is not impossible in the current standard model of particle physics. The elementary particles become massless for very high energies, before symmetry breaking, so at some point in the history of the universe this would not be a counter argument for the model. It would be like a photosphere with the whole table of particles .

Comment: Circular (massless) photon orbits are also not stable close to the event horizon @annav

Comment: @annav - Below the surface of the sphere of photons, nothing can orbit, because on that surface the orbit must be executed at speed c. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere   A spherical shell can not sustain itself based on orbiting particles.

Comment: @Buzz - From a distant observer's point of view, objects in free fall to a black hole, seem to brake near the event horizon, even considering the irresistible action of singularity at this place. This observer does not see these objects crossing the event horizon. For him, the presence of these objects certainly produces there a indestructible spherical shell. Right?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a Kerr hole, you no longer have spherical symmetry or Birchoff's theorem to assure you that a thin shell of mass $M$ will produce the same field as the black hole itself.  This, combined with the fact that the shape of a Kerr Horizon is, itself, a bit complicated (if $a > \sqrt{3}/2$, the horizon doesn't even embed into 3d flat space), this proposition becomes a bit complicated to establish in pure GR.

Answer (score -2):

Black-Hole formation is really an extension of Madame Noether's Conservation Law...where a disorganized mass of particles, in a state of 3 dimensional chaos, becomes subject to a quantum-mechanical process which 'homomorphically' transforms this chaotic state into a 2 dimensional state that has perfect Noether symmetry and equilibrium.  This transformed state consists only of radiation confined to the surface of a Schwarzschild sphere...in other words: a Black-hole.

Nature loves transforming matter (energy) into a minimally sized package (a Schwarzschild sphere) in which energy-density and gravity have attained the maximum values that nature will allow and are confined to the surface of a Schwarzschild boundary in the form of radiation.  How does nature accomplish this unique matter-to-radiation phase-change?

Comment: This seems to be missing nonsense through abuse of terminology.

Comment: An object in free fall to a black hole, can not undergo any transformation in its way, even if it is one homomorphic type , because this is one Equivalence Principle's imposition. The rest is equivalent to freefall. 
A neutron star undergoes modifications in its sub atomic structure because its parts refuse to accept the gravity effects until just before collapse.

Comment: Hello J. Bosco...thanks for your comment.  The radiation model of Black-hole structure that  I am proposing does not violate any of the existing laws of physics, but it does represent a contradiction to current Black-hole theories which postulate things like infinite densities (singularities).

Comment: Matter and gravity are synomonous with energy; but there's a limit to the density of energy that can be confined within a given volume of space: a Schwarzschild sphere.  There's just so much matter you can squeeze into a Schwarzschild "suitcase" before it "breaks" or its contents is transformed into a more manageable form of energy (radiation) that allows the "suitcase" to get bigger. The amount of energy-density confined in a given volume of space coincides with the value of the Schwarzschild radius and corresponds to a critical value of energy-density.

Comment: A critical event in the interior of an evolving BH, representing a change-in-state from matter to radiation, is preceded by an exponential increase in the momentum of particles confined within the volume of a contracting star (or any object).  As particle velocities approach the speed of light, and as distance and time between particle collisions approach zero, the energy-density of a collapsing object will reach a limit where the transformation of gravitational force can no longer be defined in terms of particle collisions.  (I welcome all critical comments regarding this new BH model).

Comment: Where is exposed your radiation model from the black holes's structure, so I can see it?

Comment: J. Bosco: A physics paper entitled "Black Hole Radiation Model (new)" is posted on the Reddit site: And thanks for offering to share information on this subject (RobertO).                         https://www.reddit.com/r/Physics/comments/a98rov/black_hole_radiation_model_new/

Answer (score -2):

- Warning uneducated thought experiment incoming.....
  Yes but on a cosmological scale, not the limited small scale folks are talking about here. The universe itself is a massive spherical black hole. The quantum fluctuations that created all the matter that we see as the observable universe are sort of minor symptom of the expanding spherical shell black hole that the big bang created. As the fluctuation that we call the big bang expanded it compressed the matter in front of it (suggesting this universe is just one inside an infinite nest) for some time until it reached a point where the shock front collapsed and created an expanding spherical shell black hole. At that point the sphere continued to expand and started to stretch the space time inside of it, and this is the reality that we experience today. The shell itself will only reach its limit when its expansion velocity reaches c. At that point its mass will be infinite and will be ripe for another shell to be born.

Comment: The universe itself is not a massive spherical black hole.