# Are mass or inertia the same thing, the same properties?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, mass, inertia, equivalence-principle

I think so. But I wold like to know another opinions to confirm.

Comment: Yes, and it's not an opinion.

Comment: Inertia and mass are related, but different concepts. Inertia is expressed by the Newton's 2nd law as $F=\dfrac{\text{d}p}{\text{d}t}$ while mass is the energy localized in the rest frame as $E=mc^2$.

Comment: @safesphere   Yes. but you also said this: "A quantum effect at the horizon dissolves the infalling matter whose energy has transferred to the gravitational field. " https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/413222/black-hole-as-a-gravitational-spherical-shell-why-not/414872#414872 So, I can synthesize and to say that mass and inertia are exactly the same thing, because only gravitacional field has this properties. Matters mass belongs to its gravitational field. Right?

Comment: No, mass comes from the energy of all fields combined, gravity, electromagnetism, strong, and weak (plus Higgs, if it exists). Normally gravity is weak and 99% of mass is the energy of the strong field (virtual gluons). As gravity increases, the time dilation converts this energy into the energy of the gravitational field. The conversion is complete at the event horizon, but for an external observer this takes an infinite time, so it is never really complete and all charge conservation laws still hold.

Comment: Also see my calculation of how gravity reduces mass (the energy of mass is converted to the energy of gravity). Formula (2) here plus the last formula: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423533/are-black-holes-black/423932#423932

Comment: @safesphere  But the gravitational field of a neutron star is identical to that one of black hole that it produced.

Comment: A black hole is smaller than a neutron star. At the radius of the neutron star their gravitational fields are the same, but at the radius of the Earth its gravitational field also is the same as of a neutron star or black hole. The key is the field at the smaller radius. The gravitational field of a black hole at the radius smaller than a neutron star is different from the gravitational field of the neutron star. Essentially the black hole gravity is just stronger until it is infinite at the horizon. Gravity is time dilation reversed. So "infinite" simply means that time stops at the horizon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but. I would say that mass is the property that underlies inertia - And also underlies gravity. I'm not sure if these distinctions matter to you.

Mass is the amount of stuff there is. It's a property of the object. Post-Einstein, it's the rest-energy of the stuff, rather than its "amount".

It so-happens that inertial mass, the property of matter that resists change in velocity (the $m$ in $F=ma$) is equal to this amount. It didn't *have* to be this way, philosophically, the two concepts are different. So as a matter of empirical fact we found that mass is the property of matter that resists changing velocity, i.e. it is the property that underlies inertia.

At the same time, we also found that mass is the property of matter that underlies gravity. Again, this needen't be the case philosophically. It's not like that the idea of "amount of rest energy" or "amount of stuff" is the *same* as the idea of "what causes gravity". But in practice, the same thing is both.