# Am I wrong to conclude that every gravitational field has its origin in a singularity point?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, singularities

If all matter "swallowed up" by a black hole becomes a singularity, what prevents this singularity from already being present in matter, in a more discreet, more diluted form?

The gravitational field of a black hole has the same properties as a planet when viewed from afar. So why can't the physical properties of the origin of this field in a black hole, in its singularity, be identical to those found at the origin of gravity within baryonic matter?

What prevents the gravitational field of matter at its origin from being composed of tiny singularities points?

Comment: Answering your question requires a theory of quantum gravity so that we understand the gravitational field of elementary particles. All such theories are speculative, so answers would be opinion-based. This makes your question off-topic. Most physicists I know expect that an eventual theory of quantum gravity will *not* have singularities of any kind.

Comment: @G.Smith - Do You mean that a eventual quantum theory of gravity doesn't even agree with the singularity inside black holes too?

Comment: I think a common view among many physicists is that in an eventual quantum theory of gravity black holes will *not* have singularities. I don’t know a lot about string theory, but I think this is true in string theory. Perhaps a string theorist can tell us.

Comment: @G.Smith - It's a nice surprise, thank you!

Comment: I'm also not a string theorist but I don't think mainstream string theory has been able to resolve what happens to a black hole singularity, even though a quantum theory of gravity should be able to do this. However there is a "fuzzball" proposal by string theorist Samir Mathur at Ohio State (and others) where the interior of the black hole doesn't exist at all, and is replaced by some kind of stringy "fuzz".

Comment: @Andrew - Here, in this question I asked, on this link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/413222/black-hole-as-a-gravitational-spherical-shell-why-not
I demonstrate not agreeing with content inside black holes. I will find out more about Samir Mathur, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any finite mass, no matter how small, were compressed into a single point in space (assuming single points in space exist) then it would form a black hole. But small black holes are not stable - they evaporate very quickly due to [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation). Since we do not observe radiation emitted by evaporating black holes all around us, we can be sure that the matter does not contain miniature black holes or singularities.

In fact, we have good reason to believe that singularities, single points in space and point particles do not exist in reality. Both of the leading candidates for a theory of quantum gravity ([string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) and [loop quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity)) avoid the need for point particles, although in different ways.

Comment: In this question, in your answer, and in the previous comments, you convinced me about what I try to know:
It seems that singularities may not exist.
Thanks!